# Xamarin SQLite - ManyToMany relationship

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, many-to-many

I have 4 classes that i deal with in my Xamarin.Forms project: Users, User_Profiles, Medicines and Medicne_Incident.

Business rules:

- Each **User** has 1 **User_Profile** (User profile is basically a detailed description of that user, User_Profile inherits from User)
- There is a *ManyToMany* relation between **Users** and the **medicines**, and so a bridge table is created: **Medicine_Incident**
- A user can have multiple Medicine_Incidents, but that incident is unique to the user.

I have no idea how to connect the dots (i.e., to have a stable relationship diagram for them).

Below are the class definitions for each of them:

**User:**

```
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool ProfileComplete { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        ProfileComplete = false;
        Username = "";
        Email = "";
        Password = "";
    }

    public User(string email, string Password)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = Password;
    }
}
```

**User_Profiles:**

```
public class User_Profiles : User
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string Postal { get; set; }

    public User_Profiles()
    {
        //Medicine = new List<Medicine>();
    }

    //?Do we need this?
    public User_Profiles(string email, string Password)
    {
        //Medicine = new List<Medicine>();
        this.Username = "";
        //this.Dob = DateTime.Today;//Probably wrong to do
        this.Gender = "";
        this.Country = "";
        this.Address = "";
        this.Province = "";
        this.Postal = "";

        //Password/Email for User
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = Password;
    }
}
```

**Medicine:**

```
public class Medicine //: User_Profiles
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Medicine_Name { get; set; }
    public string Medicine_Desc { get; set; }

    public Medicine()
    {
        Medicine_Name = "";
        Medicine_Desc = "";
        //Medicine_Incident = new List<Medicine_Incident>();
    }
}
```

**Medicine_Incident:**

```
public class Medicine_Incident : Medicine
{
    public virtual Medicine Medicine { get; set; }
    public virtual User_Profiles User_Profiles { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Dosage { get; set; }

    public Medicine_Incident()
    {
        // (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM)
        Dosage = 0;
    }
}
```

**I do my database querying in a file called "UserDatabase.cs":**

```
public class UserDatabase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public UserDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<User_Profiles>().Wait();
        database.CreateTableAsync<User>().Wait();
        database.CreateTableAsync<Medicine>().Wait();
        database.CreateTableAsync<Medicine_Incident>().Wait();
    }

    public void SaveProfileAsync(User_Profiles user)
    {
        database.InsertAsync(user);
    }

    public Task<User_Profiles> GetProfileAsync(string email, string pass)
    {
        return database.Table<User_Profiles>().Where(i => (i.Email.Equals(email)) && (i.Password.Equals(pass))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public void SaveMedicineAsync(Medicine med)
    {
        database.InsertAsync(med);
    }

    public void SaveMedicineIncidentAsync(Medicine_Incident med_inc)
    {
        database.InsertAsync(med_inc);
    }

    public Task<Medicine_Incident> GetMedicineIncidentAsync(string email, string medName, DateTime time)
    {
        return database.Table<Medicine_Incident>().Where(i => (i.User_Profiles.Email.Equals(email)) && (i.Medicine.Medicine_Name.Equals(medName)) && (i.Time.Equals(time))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Now the main thing is, i know i am doing it wrong, but how can i rectify it? Trust me when i say i spent time solving this and finding solution to this online.

NOTE:
 - I am using SQLite.
 - I have the SQLite extension in the project.

Comment: Not 100% sure what the question is, it looks like your medicine incident table is a join table, If I have the user I can find their incidents or if I have a medicine I can find the users that have used the med.

Comment: Yes, Medicine_Incident is a join table. My question was, what code to write in these classes to connect them? I have tried using ICollections and foreign keys, but get errors using them (even with SQLite Extension).

Comment: Probably not the answer you want but I would probably skip that , and just store the ID of the medicine in the incident and the ID of the user and access it that way , the other option I think would be to write the query directly.  I think the idea is to have primitive types in the ORM and if you need to make complex types you should do that out side of the ORM ...not saying its not possible just it seems like a bad idea

Comment: You're right @snowCrabs, this is the best way that I know to do that.

Comment: How would i store my incidents? in the Medicine_Incident or just the user or the Medicine? And the query, should it be like - "if the maedicineId and UserId match, the save"?

Comment: @TigerLionCheetah, see my edit. I guess it will work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sorry for the poor english

There is a lot of problems here. I guess you should read [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SQLite-with-96f22fac) and [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1057992/Using-SQLite-An-Example-of-CRUD-Operations-in-Csha) to help you learn how to model class/database in your code, but here is some tips:

- Inheritance is used to extend a class (for example: Human inherits
  from mammal that inherits from animal that inherits from living
  being)
- Your User_Profile class can have a public List  Users (that
  must be ignored by your SQLite database) and a Id [PrimaryKey]
- Your User class, the IdUser_Profile (this will define which profile
  each user have). It can be reffered to your UserProfile class...

I hope that it helps you.

**Edit**

You're right. This will not help you. I let it pass some details about your scope. Here is a more usefull information:

The only problem I see is the Medicine_Incident class. I would do so:

```
public class Medicine_Incident
{
    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdMedicine { get; set; }
    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.Ignore]
    public Medicine Medicine { get; set; }
    public int IdUser_Profiles { get; set; }
    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.Ignore]
    public User_Profiles User_Profiles { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Dosage { get; set; }

    public Medicine_Incident()
    {
        // (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM)
        Dosage = 0;
    }
}
```

And in your database query:

```
public class UserDatabase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public UserDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<User_Profiles>().Wait();
        // Don't do that (Your User's attribute will be persisted within your User_Profiles table): database.CreateTableAsync<User>().Wait();
        database.CreateTableAsync<Medicine>().Wait();
        database.CreateTableAsync<Medicine_Incident>().Wait();
    }

    public void SaveProfileAsync(User_Profiles user)
    {
        database.InsertAsync(user);
    }

    public Task<User_Profiles> GetProfileAsync(string email, string pass)
    {
        return database.Table<User_Profiles>().Where(i => (i.Email.Equals(email)) && (i.Password.Equals(pass))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public void SaveMedicineAsync(Medicine med)
    {
        database.InsertAsync(med);
    }

    public void SaveMedicineIncidentAsync(Medicine_Incident med_inc)
    {
        database.InsertAsync(med_inc);
    }

    public Task<Medicine_Incident> GetMedicineIncidentAsync(string email, string medName, DateTime time)
    {
        var user = database.Table<User_Profiles>().Where(u => u.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
        var medicine = database.Table<Medicine>().Where(m => m.Medicine_Name == medName).FirstOrDefault();
        var medInc = database.Table<Medicine_Incident>().Where(mi => mi.IdUser_Profiles == user.Id && mi.IdMedicine == medicine.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        medInc.User = user;
        medInc.Medicine = medicine;

        return medInc;
    }
}
```

SQLite doesn't handle relationships between classes when querying. To do this, use the [SQLite Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions).

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The links you have provided are not relevant to my scenario as the links do not deal with many-many or one-many relationships. As far as the Inheritance goes, Is there a problem with the UserPofile inheriting from user? I cant use Lists as SQLite wont let me use complex relations.

Comment: Did it Works? I'm glade to help.

Comment: It did, eventhough i had to remove    "medInc.User = user;
        medInc.Medicine = medicine;" Because, sql wont let me use them.